# displaying server validation errors or viewbag/tempdata messages in bootstrap modal in asp core mvc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a asp core website and I wanted to show asp-validation-summary messages and viewbag or tempdata or any message in bootstrap. After some research and experiments i found a way to do this but it is quite clumsy and not quite up to the mark.
Can you please suggest a better way to do this.

Here are my code snippets

**Controller Snippet**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UserHome(UserProfileViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                               
            AppUser user = await userrepo.GetLoggedInUserAsync(HttpContext);
            Mapper.Map<UserProfileViewModel,AppUser>(model,user);
            await userrepo.UpdateUserAccountAsync(user);
            TempData["Message"] = "Profile updated";
            return RedirectToAction("UserHome");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

**View Snippet**

```
@if(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && TempData["Message"]==null)

{

}
else
{
    <script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

});
</script>
}
            <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        @TempData["Message"]


      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made little changes in the view,
use your TempData in Javascript

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

  <!-- Modal Header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
   <div id="Message"></div>


  </div>

  <!-- Modal footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Put this lines inside the scripts

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var msg = "@TempData["Message"]";
        //Check the condition if its not empty
        if (msg != "") {

           $("#Message").text(msg);
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

});
</script>
```